# Is there any complete sample for RadDataForm?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm considering using NativeScript-Vue v7.0 for production use and looking into its validation features of data form.

I suppose `RadDataForm` would be an appropriate component for customizing validation rules, but the documentation following is for NativeScript v6.0, and the source code displayed is corrupted.

https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/dataform/dataform-validation

Is there any complete sample code that implements regex-based validation rules and customized error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation (v7): [RadDataForm Getting Started](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/dataform/getting-started)

The sample code in the link you provided ([updated](https://v7.docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/dataform/dataform-validation)) is also available on GitHub:

https://github.com/ProgressNS/nativescript-ui-samples-vue/blob/master/dataform/app/examples/Validation.ts

[`email` property with RegEx validator from the link above](https://github.com/ProgressNS/nativescript-ui-samples-vue/blob/33695bfbd1327750205baee4b868224ef0fb880e/dataform/app/examples/Validation.ts#L55)

Complete example:

```js
import { Frame } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/frame';

import { RegisteringUser } from '../data';

const description = 'Validation';

export default {
  name: 'Validation',
  description: description,
  template: `
  <Page>
    <ActionBar :title="title">
      <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" @tap="onNavigationButtonTap"></NavigationButton>
    </ActionBar>
    <StackLayout>
      <RadDataForm
        ref="dataform"
        :source="person"
        :metadata="personMetadata">
      </RadDataForm>
      <Label :text="text"
             textWrap="true"
             margin="12"
             android:color="#C73339"
             ios:color="red"
             horizontalAlignment="center"></Label>
      <Button
        text="Login"
        margin="12"
        horizontalAlignment="stretch"
        @tap="onTap()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      title: description,
      person: new RegisteringUser(),
      text: null,
      personMetadata: {
        'isReadOnly': false,
        'commitMode': 'Immediate',
        'validationMode': 'OnLostFocus',
        'propertyAnnotations':
        [
          {
            'name': 'username',
            'displayName': 'Nick',
            'index': 0,
            'validators': [
              { 'name': 'NonEmpty' },
              { 'name': 'MaximumLength', 'params': { 'length': 10 } }
            ]
          },
          {
            'name': 'email',
            'displayName': 'E-Mail',
            'index': 1,
            'editor': 'Email',
            'validators': [{
              'name': 'RegEx',
              'params': {
                'regEx': '^[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\.\\_\\%\\-\\+]{1,256}\\@telerik.com$',
                'errorMessage': 'Please provide your @telerik.com email.'
              }
            }]
          },
          {
            'name': 'password',
            'displayName': 'Password',
            'editor': 'Password',
            'index': 2,
            'validators': [
              {
                'name': 'NonEmpty',
              },
              {
                'name': 'MinimumLength',
                'params': {
                  'length': 6
                }
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'name': 'password2',
            'displayName': 'Repeat Password',
            'editor': 'Password',
            'index': 3,
            'validators': [
              {
                'name': 'NonEmpty',
              },
              {
                'name': 'MinimumLength',
                'params': {
                  'length': 6
                }
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            'name': 'age',
            'displayName': 'Age',
            'index': 4,
            'validators': [
              {
                'name': 'RangeValidator',
                'params': {
                  'minimum': 1,
                  'maximum': 100,
                  'errorMessage': 'Age must be between 1-100.',
                }
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            'name': 'agreeTerms',
            'displayName': 'Agree Terms',
            'index': 5,
            'validators': [
              {
                'name': 'IsTrueValidator',
              },
            ],
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onNavigationButtonTap() {
      Frame.topmost().goBack();
    },
    onTap() {
      let isValid = true;

      const pName = this.$refs.dataform.getPropertyByName('username');
      const pPwd = this.$refs.dataform.getPropertyByName('password');
      const pPwd2 = this.$refs.dataform.getPropertyByName('password2');

      if (pName.valueCandidate.toLowerCase() !== 'admin1') {
        pName.errorMessage = 'Use admin1 as username.';
        this.$refs.dataform.notifyValidated('username', false);
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        this.$refs.dataform.notifyValidated('username', true);
      }

      if (!pPwd.valueCandidate) {
        pPwd.errorMessage = 'Password is empty.';
        this.$refs.dataform.notifyValidated('password', false);
        isValid = false;
      }

      if (pPwd2.valueCandidate !== pPwd.valueCandidate) {
        pPwd2.errorMessage = 'Password is not the same as above.';
        this.$refs.dataform.notifyValidated('password2', false);
        isValid = false;
      } else {
        this.$refs.dataform.notifyValidated('password2', true);
      }

      if (!isValid) {
        this.text = 'Username or Password is not valid.';
      } else {
        this.text = '';
        this.$refs.dataform.commitAll();

        alert({
          title: 'Successful Login',
          message: `Welcome, ${this.person.username}`,
          okButtonText: 'OK',
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```